# Can you cleanse out of knock-up's or knocked-backs?

Tags: league-of-legends

For champions like Alistar, Orianna, Lee Sin, Gragas etc can you cleanse out of their ultimate's/skills?

Answer (score 10):

All displacement type spells (knock-back, knock-up, pulls, etc) **cannot be prevented or ended by the use of Cleanse.** Additionally, these type of spells are **not affected by Tenacity.** The only other form of Crowd Control that is not effected by tenacity or cleanse is Suppression, such as Warwick and Malzahar's ultimates.

However, it is worth noting that there are ways to **prevent these types of spells**, such as Sivir or Nocturn's shield, Morgana's Black shield, or Banshee's veil.

A lot of information about the varying effects and counters of Crowd Control types can be found here:
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crowd_control

Comment: It's worth noting that, while you CANNOT Cleanse out of displacement abilities((Via Cleanse or Quicksilver Sash)), through quicksilver sash you can cleanse out of the STUN portion of them, allowing you to flash DURING the displacement. I'm unfortunately at work so I can't link it, but the Quicksilver Sash article on the same wiki has this information.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot, they are nearly instantaneous and are displacement abilities. It would be like asking if you can cleanse out of Janna's ultimate. It just pushes you or pops you up, knockups require the champ to be next to you/very close making it difficult to land them - so easily manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. However, this does not prevent the knock-up animation from completing. It only allows you to cast mobility abilities during the animation, like Flash or Vayne's Tumble, which allows you to escape the knock-up.

[Here's a Reddit thread covering this mechanic.](https://www.reddit.com/r/summonerschool/comments/34sm5i/a_tip_regarding_qss_and_knockup_cc_eg_vi_ult_that/)

[Here's a video showcasing this mechanic.](https://youtu.be/9_MkHaC_I1s?t=2284)

[Here's an instructional video describing how to perform this mechanic.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmsOO4ult20)

Answer (score 0):

You can only cleanse Debuff´s, Knock-Backs and other´s of the kind are not considered Debuff´s, but environment events!